# how to send a json string to a .NET REST service from java?

Tags: .net, android, web-services

i am trying to send a json string from my android client to my .net Rest service...
can anyone help me in this issue?

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://myURL");

 JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
 json.put("name", "i am sample");
 StringEntity str = new StringEntity(json.toString());
 str.setContentType("application/json; charset=utf-8");
 str.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json; charset=utf-8"));
 post.setEntity(str);
 HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

Response is bad request. am i sending the json object as string? is this code correct?

Comment: Do you wanna publish the code (service attributes whcih defines post/get and the routing url) for .net web service? Not the whole implementation but where it defines URL routing and get/post.

Comment: @aliostad: this is my android client code.in myURL i specified my URL(http://10.242.48.54/restinsert/Service1.svc/CreateCustomer/Data). this service is implemented in .net which accepts only string as its input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the solution is

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://10.242.48.54/restinsert/Service1.svc/save");
JSONStringer json = new JSONStringer()
.object() 
 .key("cname").value(name)
 .key("cmail").value(email)

.endObject();

StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json.toString(), "UTF-8");
                     entity.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");//text/plain;charset=UTF-8
                     entity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
                     request.setEntity(entity); 
                     // Send request to WCF service 
                     DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                     HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

This will send json object string, so in .net the request should have object parameter...

Answer (score 2):

For anyone having the same issue, here's a quick fix: 
 - The webservice is expecting an object which includes a property of type String.
In order to make this work, you must have a DataContract of the "expected" object.

For example, instead of asking for a string, create a class for your data:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyJSonString
{
 [DataMember]
    public String MyString {get;set;}
}
```

So, in your WCF method declaration you would have:

```
public void GetMyJsonString(MyJSonString mystring){...}
```

In you Java side, you have:

```
JSONStringer json = new JSONStringer().object().key("MyString").value("Hello!").endObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks valid except the following header:

```
str.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json; charset=utf-8"));
```

Content-encodings are described here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.5

Comment: if i specify other than application/json,it is not accepting any values!

Comment: Are you sure that you've tried with specifying only the content-type header?

Comment: yes! In post i specified only content-type header, is there any thing that i have to add in that other then this? if so please let me know

Comment: Try with putting the content-type on the `post` variable instead. I think that putting the specifications on a `entity` will produce a multipart post. I found an example on the net: http://localtone.blogspot.com/2009/07/post-json-using-android-and-httpclient.html